# Delphi Проверка прав доступа на сетевую папку

Tags: delphi

Есть сетевая папка 'server_z/photo'. В нее идет запись картинок. Нужно перед добавлением картинок добавить проверку на доступ к этой папке. Если пользователь не в домене, то при попытке открытия этой папки нужно предлагать ввести сетевой пароль (стандартное окошко как в проводнике). 
Пробовала использовать directoryexists. Он всегда возвращает true, даже если доступа нет.

Answer (score 1):

Решила проблему следующим образом:

```
var
  SR: TSearchRec;
  prevDir: string;
begin
  prevDir := ExtractFileDir(FrmMain.catalogs_path);
  try
    if FindFirst(prevDir + '\*.*', faDirectory, SR) <> 0 then
      MessageBox(handle, PChar('Нет доступа к директории ' + prevDir),
        PChar('Ошибка'), MB_ICONSTOP + MB_OK);
  finally
    FindClose(SR);
  end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, правда с подключением сетевого диска. [Connect to a password protected shared folder over network using Delphi](http://www.codeexplain.com/code/c53eeaac-dca4-421a-a103-526528c0ab4b)

Дискуссии по WNetAddConnection2 [тут](http://www.sql.ru/forum/960827/vopros-po-wnetaddconnection2) и [тут](http://www.programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=134159)

а вот вопрос без использования [Mapping a Network Drive WITHOUT WNetAddConnection2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371309/mapping-a-network-drive-with-delphi-without-wnetaddconnection2)

```
function ConnectShare(Drive, RemotePath, UserName, Password :    String):Integer;
var
  NRW : TNetResource;
begin
 with NRW do
 begin
   dwType := RESOURCETYPE_ANY;
   if Drive <> '' then
     lpLocalName := PChar(Drive)
   else
     lpLocalName := nil;
     lpRemoteName := PChar(RemotePath);
     lpProvider := '';
  end;
  Result := WNetAddConnection2(NRW, PChar(Password), PChar(UserName), 0);
end;

function DisconnectShare(Drive : String):Integer;
begin
  Result := WNetCancelConnection2(PChar(Drive), 0, false);
end;
```

Также можно получить доступ с помощью WMI: [Manipulating local/remote files and folders using Delphi and WMI](https://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/07/21/manipulating-localremote-files-and-folders-using-delphi-and-wmi/)

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вопрос проще и правильнее решается изменением подхода к проблеме:

1. Лишний раз спрашивать у пользователя ввод логина пароля не лучший вариант организации юзабилити.
2. Ограничением прав на выполнение каких либо операций должно заниматься приложение.
3. Не каждый кто может писать в сетевую шару должен иметь права оттуда читать, а тем более читать что то записанное другими пользователями.

Более правильный вариант использовать имперсонализацию под «сервисного» (скрытого) пользователя для получения доступа к сетевому ресурсу на время выполнения записи/чтения.

```
function SaveFileToServer(AFileStream: TMemoryStream): String;

var
  Token: THandle;
  DirectoryName: String;
  FullFileName: String;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Result := GenerateFileName;
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Stream.LoadFromStream(AFileStream);
   // EncryptStream(Stream); если нужно
   // Имперсонализация под пользователя для работы с файловым сервером
VerifyOSError(Windows.LogonUser(PChar(SUserName), PChar('DomainName'),
  PChar(SUserPass), LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS,
  LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, Token));
try
  VerifyOSError(ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(Token));
  try

    FullFileName := //Path;
    Stream.Position := 0;
    Stream.SaveToFile(FullFileName);
  finally
    RevertToSelf;
  end;
finally
  CloseHandle(Token);
end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Stream);
  end;
end;
```